# Speeding up filtering Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro for Excel that is searching for two unique criteria and counting and summing all data that contains the criteria in the proper fields. I have been able to do this with AutoFilters, but my code runs extremely slow. It needs to churn through almost 25,000 rows, and it got through about 180 in 5 minutes which is not ideal. I am wondering if there is a better, more efficient way to do this.

My code is:

```
For i = 2 To lr2
    sh1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=sh2.Cells(i, 1)

    sh1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=sh2.Cells(i, 2)

    count = sh1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.count
    sh2.Cells(i, 3).Value = (count - 1)

    Set rng = sh1.Range("G2:G" & lr1)
    sum = sh1.Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

    sh2.Cells(i, 4).Value = sum
Next i
```

sh1 and sh2 are worksheets 1 and 2, and lr2 is the number of the last row in the reference spreadsheet in sh2.

Comment: Why not use SUMIFS()?

Comment: Hmm, so something along the lines of (inside the loop)
summing if the cell in column 3 AND column 5 contain the requested data?

Comment: yes; `sum = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sh1.Range("G:G"),sh1.Range("C:C"),sh2.Cells(i, 1),sh1.Range("E:E"),sh2.Cells(i, 2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better yet get rid of the loop completely:

```
With sh2
    With .Range("D2:D" & lr2)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS('" & sh1.Name & "'!C7:C7,'" & sh1.Name & "'!C3:C3,RC1,'" & sh1.Name & "'!C5:C5,RC2)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    With .Range("C2:C" & lr2)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS('" & sh1.Name & "'!C3:C3,RC1,'" & sh1.Name & "'!C5:C5,RC2)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Wow. This is amazing. Thanks so much!! If you don't mind me asking, what is the reasoning for having the single then double quotation marks after the open parenthesis in the SUMIFS( part?

Comment: `Sh1` is a vba variable, so we need to remove it from the string and concatenate it.  The `'` is in case `sh1.Name` has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing anything that reads and/or writes in a very large range of cells, I would recommend converting the range to an array and iterating over that (and then write the array back to the range if necessary). Try code that looks something like this:

```
Dim ReadArray() as Variant
ReadArray = MyRange

Dim Count as Long
Dim Criteria1 as String, Criteria2 as String

Criteria1 = "Alpha"
Criteria2 = "Bravo"

Dim Row as long, Col as long
For Row = 1 to Ubound(ReadArray, 1)
    for Col = 1 to Ubound(ReadArray, 2)
        if ReadArray(Row, Col) = Criteria1 or ReadArray(Row, Col) = Criteria2 then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    next Col
Next Row
```